# Trying to read a file and loop through at the same time

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to this so please move this topic if it's in the wrong place or something else.

**Problem:** *(Quick note: This is all in Python)* I am trying to go through these 100 or so files, each with the same number of columns, and take certain columns of the input (the same ones for each file) and write them in a new file. However, these 100 files don't necessarily all have the same number of rows. In the code below, filec is in a loop and continues altering throughout the 100 files. I am trying to get these certain columns that I want by looking at the number of rows in each txt file and looping that many times then taking the numbers I want.

```
    filec = open(string,'r').read().split(',')
    x = len(filec.readlines())
```

I realize the issue is that filec has become a list after using the split function and was originally a string when I used .read(). How would one go about finding the number of lines, so I can loop through the number of rows and get the positions in each row that I want?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to know the number of lines. You can iterate directly with `for line open(string,'r').readlines():`

Comment: (Sorry I don't know how to write code as a comment). Perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment or I did not explain clearly, my bad...so basically after the two lines of code above, I said "for i in range(x) a = 20i + 8 b = 20i + 9 c = 20i+9" where filec[a], filec[b], filec[c] were the values in each row that I wanted. Sorry for being unable to write code well here, I am new :(

Comment: @JulienBernu:  No need for the [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines):  "Note that it's already possible to iterate on file objects using `for line in file: ...` without calling `file.readlines()`."  Combine with [`enumerate(opened_file, start=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for a count of lines processed.

Comment: Oh thats another way...I didn't know you could go through lines like that. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest _The Python Tutorial_, section [7.2.  Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), especially subsection [7.2.1. Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Thanks so much for the links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
filec = open (filename, 'r')
lines = filec.readlines ()

for line in lines:
    words = line.split(',')
    # Your code here
```

Excuse me if there are any errors, I'm doing this on mobile.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would upvote if I could but I have less than 15 reputation since I'm new :P

Comment: You can upvote and it still counts. It just won't show up on the vote count.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case I guess I did upvote :). Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence you could/should accept an answer if it works for you.

Comment: Is this the required answer?

Comment: Yup, this worked. Thanks so much! I don't know how to "accept" an answer @ShreyasMurali. Oh thanks above

Answer (score 0):

As you are just looking for the count of rows, then how about this -

```
t = tuple(open(filepath\filename.txt, 'r'))

print len(t)
```

Comment: Hi, pardon my ignorance, but what does tuple do? Are you saying to basically replace the first line of my code with your first line and use len(t) to denote the length?

Comment: I don't know if tuple takes care of the fact that I need to split('). If it does, then please correct me! Thanks again.

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence: `tuple` is pretty much like a `list`, its just that its `immutable` (you can't modify a `tuple`). You can iterate through each item and use `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep the code clear, it is very possible to do with fewer lines. take in a list of file names, give out a dictionary, mapping the filename to the column you wanted (as a list).

```
def read_col_from_files(file_names, column_number):
    ret = {}
    for file_name in file_names:
        with open(file_name) as fp:
            column_for_file = []
            for line in fp:
                columns = line.split('\t')
                column_for_file.append(columns[column_number])
        ret[file_name] = column_for_file
    return ret
```

I have assumed you have tab delimited columns. Call it like this:

```
data = read_col_from_files(["file_1.txt", "/tmp/file_t.txt"], 5)
```

Here is a sensible shortening of the code using a list comprehension

```
def read_col_from_files(file_names, column_number):
    ret = {}
    for file_name in file_names:
        with open(file_name) as fp:
            ret[file_name] = [line.split('\t')[column_number] for line in fp]
    return ret
```

And here is how to do it on the command line:

```
cat FILENAMES | awk '{print $3}'
```